# How to convert VS2010 express solution and project file in VS2012 ultimate?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2010

Long back ago I developed the application in Visual studio 2010 express edition. Somehow I need it now. But I am not having VS2010 express. Currently I am having the Visual studio 2012 ultimate version. I tried by right click on solution file opened in notepad and changed the version to 2012. I think solution file is converted and opened in VS2012. but internal .vbproj file in showing not compatible. 
 Getting following error : for .vbproj file

```
Unsupported
This version of Visual Studio does not have the following project types installed or does not support them. You can still open these projects in the version of Visual Studio in which they were originally created.
```

And following withing same box : for .sln file

```
No changes required
These projects can be opened in this version of Visual Studio without changing them. They will continue to open in Visual Studio 2010 SP1 and in this version of Visual Studio.
```

What can I do?

[image]

Comment: Did you tried to open without editing the solution file? It should convert it.

Comment: yes I tried it. but given same error.

Comment: Is the `VB` project type installed on VS2012?

Comment: not actully before. but from tools->import export settings, I settled up VB.

Comment: Try to go to Help -> About Mocrosoft Visual Studio. You should see a Visual Basic 2012 entry in the list.

Comment: yes. but what i have to do with it?

Comment: Well, then I'd create the project in VS2012 and add the source files manually.

Comment: ummmm I was thinking the same... alas.. this is how VS tool support compatibility with its own versions...